# printing object not triggering error in PHP

Tags: php

According to the book I am reading, `print`ing object that does not have `__toString()` implemented should throw an error:

```
Object of class popp\ch04\batch22\Person could not be converted to string ...
```

When I try to do this, I am getting a message `Process finished with exit code 255`, but no descriptive error. I am using PhpStorm.

```
<?php

    class Person{}

    $person = new Person();

    try {
        print $person;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        print $e;
    }
```

Is there a switch I should enable to receive errors?

Comment: Have you disabled PHP error messages/logging?

Comment: There is `<?php`, at the start and no, I just installed PhpStorm and haven't played with any error settings

Comment: Most likely `error_reporting()` is set to none, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file (after `<?php`).

Comment: Please try to put this line at the beginnig of your file: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: That said, errors should not be displayed in production environments (just in development). They should always be logged though. So `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` is just for development, `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` is for production. `error_reporting(E_ALL);` should always be set though.

Comment: Thanks @N'Bayramberdiyev and Qirel. That did the trick.

Comment: Now the error is displayed, but not caught. Is this the type of error that cannot get caught?

Comment: Its not an exception, so no. Its a fatal error, which means you can implement something with `register_shutdown_function()` - but not through an exception.

Comment: It's discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error#answer-2146171).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure PHP to generate errors by itself instead of adding error reporting code to PHP operators manually.

`error_reporting` should always be set to `E_ALL`.

**Development:**

`display_errors` should be set to `1`.

**Production:**

`display_errors` should be set to `0`.

`log_errors` should be set to `1`.

Read more about [error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).

Comment: Great read! The author says `the use of @ operator` is bad practice. What does `@` do? I googled the list of PHP operators, but haven't found anything about `@` at all.

Comment: It suppresses errors. You can read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Comment: Thanks man!  At https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#code it says that the error handling code should be included in bootstrap file. I am not sure what is the usual way of telling PHP to `include` a file in files. Is this something that can be done in `php.ini` or do you need to rely on some coding principles?

Comment: If you have a custom error handler, it should be included in your bootstrap file which refers to _the process of loading the environment a program (or a script, in the case of PHP) needs to operate._ ([source](https://www.binpress.com/php-bootstrapping-crash-course/)). If you let PHP handle errors, configuration values above should be set in `php.ini`.

Comment: And you may want to read about [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).